# How to do a firestore query in chronological order on creation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I built a collection and added some documents sequentially (a few seconds apart).  firestore generated each doc.id automatically.

<s>In the documentation it says each doc.id key consists of a timestamp part and random part (presumably to ensure there are no key collisions).</s>
 Edit: I had read this on an unrelated blog post, so I've removed this to avoid confusion.

<s>Since</s> If the key were to contain some (hidden) chronology, is it possible to do a firestore query based on this key and thus get the result set in ascending or descending chronological order?

Comment: *firebaser here* "In the documentation it says each doc.id key consists of a timestamp part and random part" That should not be anywhere in the Firestore documentation. Can you point me to where you found it, so we can fix it?

Comment: My notes are a bit fragmented, but I may have wrongly got the from reading this (push id's aren't firestore ids so not sure this was the only thing I read) https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: That is a blog post about the Firebase Realtime Database, which indeed does use timestamps as part of its auto-generated keys. It does explicitly not apply to Cloud Firestore, which (as Grimthorr answered) document that you need to add your own timestamp if you want to be able to get the results in chronological order.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for clarifying. I've edited the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cloud Firestore auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering, and cannot be relied-upon to be chronological. To order your documents chronologically, you should add your own timestamp field to the documents.

From the [Firestore add a document documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> **Important**: Unlike "push IDs" in the Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering. If you want to be able to order your documents by creation date, you should store a timestamp as a field in the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Made this firebase function to add my missing 'createdAt' field to all of my user documents on firestore. It fixes 450 documents at a time (there's a hard limit on 500) and returns the list of their ids.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');  
admin.initializeApp(/*.....*/);
let db = admin.firestore();

exports.fixUserBase = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
      let usersRef = db.collection('users');
      const batch = db.batch();
      let newCount = 0;
      var changed = [];
      return usersRef.get().then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
          return [];
        }  
        else {
          console.log('Received ' + snapshot.length + 'user documents.');
        }
        snapshot.forEach(docDataOrg => {
          if (newCount>450){
            if (newCount==451) console.log('Stoping at 450');
            newCount += 1;
          } else {
            var docData = docDataOrg.data();
            var userID = docDataOrg.id;

            var createdAt = docDataOrg["createTime"];
            if (!(docData["createdAt"]!=null)){  
              console.log('updateing createdAt for ' + docData["email"]);
              batch.update(usersRef.doc(userID), {"createdAt":createdAt.seconds})
//I prefer seconds to timestamp, remove the '.seconds' if you prefer otherwise
              newCount += 1;
              changed.push(userID);
            }
          }
        });
        console.log('returning ' + changed);
        return batch.commit().then(function(){
          return changed;
        }); 
      });
    });
```

This code could have saved me some good hours, happy to share.