# Cloud Firestore realtime database why is getting all items

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using vuejs and I want to get last created item in Firestore realtime database but when I run this code it's getting all items in database

```
getRealtime() {
        db.collection("items").onSnapshot(doc => {
          doc.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log(change.doc.data());
            }
        });

        })
      }
```

Comment: Please read the documentation how to retrieve data https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly that - querying for all the documents in the "items" collection.  There is no default ordering for documents.  If you want to get only the newest document, you need to add some sort of timestamp field in each document, and query using that field.  You will also have to use a limit() specifier to limit to the newest 1.

See also:

- [How to do a firestore query in chronological order on creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620650/how-to-do-a-firestore-query-in-chronological-order-on-creation)
- [Sort X most recent Firestore documents Ascending by timestamp, and add in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920612/sort-x-most-recent-firestore-documents-ascending-by-timestamp-and-add-in-real-t)